# Java : Map and set to Uppercase

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Under my **spring boot** app i ve this restfull service method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "objects/{objectId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<ObjectDTO > getStoreById(@PathVariable("objectId") String storeId) throws DomainResourceNotFoundException {
        Object obj= ObjService.getObjById(objectId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new DomainResourceNotFoundException(Store.class.getSimpleName(), objectId));
        ObjectDTO objDTO = CustomMapperFactory.getMapper().map(obj, ObjectDTO .class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(objDTO , HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My problem is when mapping , the resulting object **objDTO ** is in this format:

```
"attributeone": "aaa"
"attributetWO": "bbb"
```

my purpose is to convert to uppercase , while mapping " the attributes names , to result on this format:

```
"ATTRIBUTEONE": "aaa"
"ATTRIBUTEOTWO": "bbb"
```

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Your StoreDTO has lowercase field names? Can you show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON keys reflect the attribute names in StoreDTO. Depending on the library that you use for serialization, you can override the attribute names with `@JSONProperty` (`com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty` for Jackson, which is the most used) :

```
@JSONProperty("ATTRIBUTEONE")
private String attributeone;
```

If you want to do it for all attributes, you can use this:

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    new PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy()
)
```

But the result will be `ATTRIBUTE_ONE`, not `ATTRIBUTEONE`. If you really need `ATTRIBUTEONE`, you can implement your own strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Generic way to do this would be extending and using your own `PropertyNamingStrategy`, like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
PropertyNamingStrategy pns = new PropertyNamingStrategy.PropertyNamingStrategyBase() {
    @Override
    public String translate(String propertyName) {
        return propertyName.toUpperCase();
    }

};
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setPropertyNamingStrategy(pns);
```